# What is minSdkVersion for Amazon Android in-app purchase SDK?

Tags: android, sdk, in-app-purchase, version

Some Amazon docs hint that it is 10, but examples run with 8. So what is the correct/safe/practical answer?

Answer (score 0):

It is the minimum SDK requirement for application, App Developers put this variable to not install this app earlier version of device than min SDK version, it is just a safe check, to not install the app on incompatible devices

Comment: Perhaps I should ask whether the Amazon in-app library works in SDK lvl 8 device, or does it require lvl 10?

Comment: Yup, it will work fine on Android SDK 6 or Later, so that's mean you can easily install it on SDK level 8

Answer (score 0):

According to wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kindle_Fire the first Kindle Fire was based on Android 2.3.4 which is based on Android SDK version 10. Therefore there is no benefit to use minSdkVersion lower than 10.

If you use minSdkVersion lower than 10 your app will run on all Kindle Fires because new Android versions can run apps written for older Android versions.

However if you specify min SDK version 10 you can use all APIs that is available in the SDK version 10 but is not available in the Android SDK version 8.